# Google Web Fonts is not working on Android 4.2.2 with Khmer language

Tags: android, css, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm trying to show Khmer language in Android. In Android version 4.1.2 and 4.4+, the Khmer language is working fine. But in Android version 4.2.2 any Khmer language is not displayed even a character. I got a blank space text.

This is the example of Khmer language that's using Google web fonts : http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Battambang#charset
. You can open it any browser that support @font-face it will display the Khmer text except Android 4.2.2.

Every Khmer websites I opened it with Android 4.2.2, I see only a blank space too like http://news.sabay.com.kh, http://kohsantepheapdaily.com.kh, ...

Please somebody know how to solve this problem. I tested with emulator and real device like Sony and Samsung that's using Android 4.2.2.

Update: in google web fonts, the problem is only Khmer language is not displaying. the other fonts are working. try here : https://www.google.com/fonts in Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 1):

On our custom font we have text-rendering: optimizeLegibility enabled. It was causing the font to not display in android 4.2.2. We use the font for custom symbols.

I have been debugging this sort of problem for the past week. I do not know if this will solve your issue, but it seems to be the same problem.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I wasn't sure @Deduplicator so I erred towards caution.

Comment: Best I can say is I had a problem that presented identically to the one described here, the solution that worked for me was to turn off text-rendering: optimizeLegibility. It then began displaying. The OP needs to provide feedback as to whether or not this fixes their issue as well. It very well might, but I do not have enough information to actually test the solution. There's very little in way of solutions to this issue, but the problem is documented. I hope it solves someone's issue, since it solved mine.

Comment: @KalmanHazins I do not have a different question. This would have been my exact question. Font not displaying on android 4.2.2 that works on other browsers just fine. It boils down to the same issue. Rather than leaving a question unanswered I provided the best solution I found to an issue that presents itself identically. Alternatively I could have posted my question only to answer it myself, but then I'm not providing any help to someone with a problem presenting similarly.

Comment: Fair enough. It sounded more like a comment ;)

Comment: This fixed it for me. This would of been a pain to find otherwise, thanks!